# NPE on inflating layout from different package

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I inflate a layout from a different apk (plugin) than mine (same signature) and embed it into my Activity class (core).

```
XmlResourceParser freeLayoutRes = getLayoutResourceByResourceId(R.layout.freelayout);
View freeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(freeLayout.getContext()).inflate(freeLayoutRes, freeLayout);
```

The freeLayout is the parent for the embeddable freelayoutres. The getLayoutResourceByResourceId-method is a call to the core package which gets the resource by the packagemanager, like this:

`getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(pluginapp).getLayout(layoutId))`

This works well, but some users reported me a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:435)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
        at ....
```

I can't explain and reproduce why (and when) the error occur. On my test devices and on different emulators the issue didn't appeared so far. There is also no hint in the users stacktraces to solve this problem (different devices, different Android versions, on app startup, after returning to Activity).

**EDIT:** It seems it happens mostly on Amazon Kindle Fire devices (Android 2.3.4 and 4.0.4)

Does anybody see a problem? If more information is needed, please ask.

Any help and hints will be great,
Danny

Comment: Maybe they don't have the other apk installed? Or they installed in on sdcard which isn't available at the moment? Just ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply koljaTM. I forgot to mention that the first code snippet is executed by the plugin and the second one in the core. So its safe that the plugin is available. It is also checked on core startup if one (or more) plugins are installed.